# boost::variant - Why a template parameter has higher precedence than a const string parameter

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-variant

I am witnessing a behavior in the following code that I don't understand. The point is that if I declare the second overload of `operator()` like either of the following:

```
bool operator()(T other) const
bool operator()(const T &other) const
```

The output of program is:

> string

But if I use the following declaration:

```
bool operator()(T &other) const
```

The output will be:

> other type

Can someone please explain why `operator()(const string &other)` is not being called in the latter case?

```
#include "boost/variant/variant.hpp"
#include "boost/variant/apply_visitor.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef variant<string, int> MyVariant;


class StartsWith
    : public boost::static_visitor<bool>
{
public:
    string mPrefix;
    bool operator()(const string &other) const
    {
        cout << "string" << endl;
        return other.compare(0, mPrefix.length(), mPrefix) == 0;
    }
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(T &other) const
    {
        cout << "other type" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    StartsWith(string const& prefix):mPrefix(prefix){}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    MyVariant v(string("123456"));
    apply_visitor(StartsWith("123"), v);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `const` problem here.

You are passing not const object to `apply_visitor` - so not const object members are passed to applied visitor. So in your case it is `string&` - reference to string type. This template is exact match for it:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator()(T &other) const
```

So it is selected. This function is not exact match - it is skipped:

```
bool operator()(const string &other) const
```

Of course if you provide that operator:

```
bool operator()(string &other) const
```

then it would be selected, since non template function are considered before template one.

So solution is: either provide method in your visitor which takes string reference (not const) - or pass const variant to apply...

First solution - remove const from string operator:

```
bool operator()(/*const*/ string &other) const
//              ^^^^^^^^^ remove it
```

Second solution - pass const object:

```
const MyVariant& cv = v;
apply_visitor(StartsWith("123"), cv);
//                               ^^ const object passed here
```

Third solution - add const specifier to general visitor:

```
template<typename T>
bool operator()(const T &other) const
//              ^^^^^
```

Solutions 1st and 3rd are the better than 2nd - you should pass consistent visitor to your variant, const has strong meaning when compiler has to select appropriate function.

Comment: As a type freak, I would say that the **3rd** solution is **best**, as-in: **const-correct**. There is no reason to take the parameter by non-const reference if you are not going to modify it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In this very case you are right. I did not mention `T&&` - probably it would be the best - but there are many SO posts  discussing difference between `T&&` and `const T &` so I did not want to make this unnecessary mix here...